# Generate r x c contingency tables with bi-variate normal distribution in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, contingency

I want to generate contingency tables from bi-variate normal distribution using R. One way to generate tables using multi nominal distribution with rmultinom and other will be `r2dtable`, but i want to generate the cross classified data using bivariate normal with different correlated structure.

I have tried generating samples from bi-variate normal distribution with mean 0 and sigma as diag(2). After this I don't know to construct contingency tables.

```
library(MASS)

x<-mvrnorm(n=100, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=diag(2))
```

Please help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more about what the contingency table is supposed to look like? I guess you will have to bin the data first into buckets since (at least to my knowledge) contingency tables are designed for categorical variables. is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @jludewig : I just want to generate R x C contingency tables but data (i.e) cell counts should be from bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: What is are your table column and row names supposed to be (ie what are your cells)?

Comment: @jludewig : cells in the table should be positive value and the nature of the cell is count and its a frequency distribution of the variables. For example, consider a 2 x 2 table from this link : [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table), this table can be generated with rmultinom function in r but I want to generate like this from bivariate normal distribution. Hope this will make you clear.

Comment: with a multinomial variable you are looking at counts for different *categories* (think of your data as (A,A,B,A,A,B)) which will define the cells in the contingency tables. with normal data you are looking at *continuous* values so your variable can take any value within a certain range (eg (0.7482, -0.8353, -0.7859, 0.9191, 0.6021, -0.2223, 0.5293, -0.6382)). so it is not clear how to create a contingency table, you will probably have to bin the data first. are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: What i want is that, i want to transform a set of bivariate real numbers into a set of count values and then I can make these into tabular representation or contingency tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a contingency table from your continuous data you will first have to transform it into categorical data and then do the counts on the categories. You will have to define breaks to something that makes sense for your analysis:

```
library(MASS)

x<-mvrnorm(n=100, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=diag(2))

x <- apply(x,FUN = function(y) {cut(y,breaks = c(-Inf,-0.5,0.5,Inf))},MARGIN = 2)

table(x[,1],x[,2])
```

Comment: Thank you! Your idea is one way of transforming. I will improve this to my needs.